# What is a positive descriptor for someone that doesn't care about anything/is always neutral?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes a personality/person (not in a negative but neutral/positive way) that doesn't care abut anything, has a neutral opinion about most things, is very care free/laxed, etc. The closest I could think of is narcissist but it's not quite right. Is there such a word?

I guess an example would be like "Dave doesn't care if we have a salad, a burger, or a soup for lunch, he is a/very ________."

Thanks.

Comment: narcissist is not remotely similar.

Comment: And what’s wrong with your own “***carefree***”?

Comment: Before you asked the question, did you search for synonyms for words that are close but not quite right? If so, you should tell about your research in your question, and if not, you should search before asking.

Comment: Dave is very **hungry**

Comment: @jsejcksn  Good call.

Comment: Since *neutral* suits your needs perfectly, you're really asking for its synonyms. http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/neutral

Comment: What about **happy-go-lucky**? Merriam-Webster's website says it means _blithely unconcerned :  carefree_. It doesn't fit your example too well, though.

Comment: This question is all over the place, with posters providing many one-liner non-anwers without any explanation of context. Please try to tighten up your question.

Answer (score 14):

If the person is eager to help or please, consider **accomodating** that has a positive connotation.

> Definition : having an easygoing and cheerful disposition;
>
> Example : *Please, make a special effort to be accommodating!*

If the person is uncaring, consider **indifferent**, which is negative.

> Definition :  Having no marked feeling for or against; without concern; apathetic; uninterested;
>
> Example : *Are you really this indifferent to the fact that the two
> boys were  hurt?*

Answer (score 12):

Such people are ***flexible***.

> "Dave doesn't care if we have a salad, a burger, or a soup for lunch,
>   he is very ***flexible***."

M-W:

> **[flexible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flexible)**
>   *adjective*
>
> : willing to change or to try different things
>
> Whatever you want to do is fine with me. I'm flexible.

We can also call them ***open-minded***.

M-W:

> **[open–minded](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open%E2%80%93minded)**
>   *adjective*
>
> : willing to consider different ideas or opinions

Comment: I think the best word would be "impartial".  Has no negative connotations.  Is cons ice.  For some reason I wasn't able to answer.

Answer (score 10):

> [laid-back](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/laid-back) (laidback)
>
> having a relaxed or casual atmosphere or character; easygoing
>
> relaxed in style, character, or behaviour; easy-going and unhurried

*Laid-back* has a neutral/positive connotation and describes a person who is relaxed and rarely (or never) feels/shows stress in their day-to-day life.

> Dave doesn't care if we have a salad, a burger, or soup for lunch; he is very laidback.

Note: Most online dictionaries list the word as hyphenated, but the unhyphenated version seems to be overtaking (ever so slowly). ([ngram for laidback/laid-back 1958-2008](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=laidback%2Claid-back&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1958&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Claidback%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blaidback%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLaidback%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Claid%20-%20back%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blaid%20-%20back%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BLaid%20-%20back%3B%2Cc0))

Answer (score 7):

***Easy going***

This has a very positive feel, kind of like *easy to please*.

1. not easily worried or angered; relaxed and rather casual; calm.

Random House: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/easygoing

---

**Edit:** A couple additional ideas

***even-keeled***

I'm not finding a definition that fits my idea about this word.  Here's something close:

> *on an even keel*: regular and well-balanced and not likely to change suddenly

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/on-an-even-keel

***even-tempered***

> easygoing; calm

Random House: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/even-tempered

Answer (score 5):

May not be not quite right, but it's an interesting possibility. How about *blasé*?

M-W:

> [*blasé*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blase): having or showing a lack of excitement or interest in
>   something especially because it is very familiar

Your example:

> "Dave doesn't care if we have a salad, a burger, or a soup for lunch. He is very *blasé* about most things."

Comment: Why did this get a downvote? It's the only answer that has the connotation of disengagement that the OP seeks.

Comment: @deadrat That's what I thought. Sometimes the users on this site baffle me.

Comment: @deadrat there be trolls, there be random downvotes. Also someone does not like french-sounding words. Don't dwell too much on such stuff. It happens everywhere. But I came here to suggest this word, all I can do now is upvote you, Richard.

Comment: @Mindwin I'm fine with downvotes, but I'd appreciate some sort of rationale ... so there's an opportunity for further exchange. Thanks.

Comment: @RichardKayser [sometimes there isn't a rationale, or it is quite irrational.](http://quotegeek.com/quotes-from-movies/fight-club/5185/)

Comment: @Mindwin The surplus of dwelling is the time I waste answering questions on this site, and it dwarfs the time I spend noting driveby downvotes. We can't know whether these votes are trollish, but they seem too sporadic for that. I think they're from lazy, discourteous users, and my objection is that they may mislead the ignorant who come here to ask for help in good faith. I don't mind anonymous downvotes given to answers with critical comments. We can assume they're agreements with the criticism.

Comment: @Mindwin Love that movie, almost as much as The Godfather.

Comment: @deadrat Agree completely.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that such a person is [***agreeable***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agreeable):

> ready or willing to agree : willing to do or allow something

[Meriam-Webster]

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to say, as a single-word description, that these types of people are quite ***passive***.

> ***[passive](https://www.google.fi/search?q=define%3Apassive&rct=j)*** (*adjective*): accepting or allowing what happens or what others do, without active response or resistance.

To directly address your example:

> Dave doesn't care if we have a salad, a burger, or a soup for lunch, he is very passive.

Answer (score 1):

I would describe such a person as [Sanguine](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sanguine). although the definition the folks at Merriam Webster give:

> confident and hopeful

does not seem to fit.  I had always seen this used to indicate an even temperament and the example sentences at m-w seem to bear this out. Perhaps I have been mis-using this word

Answer (score 0):

How about *apathetic*

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apathetic):

> not having or showing much emotion or interest

Although, from your post its hard to tell if the person *does* care/have emotions, but is just very agreeable

Answer (score 0):

Consider **laid-back**

> relaxed and easy-going.

It fits the context here to refer to someone who doesn't care much about things and is happy either ways. Using it in your example:

> Dave doesn't care if we have a salad, a burger, or a soup for lunch, he is a very *laid-back* person."

---

Another alternative would be **happy-go-lucky**

> cheerfully unconcerned about the future.

Both are somewhat positive words.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options to consider:

> **insouciant**: a relaxed and happy way of behaving without feeling worried or guilty ([Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/insouciance)).
>
> **nonchalant**: (of a person or manner) feeling or appearing casually calm and relaxed; not displaying anxiety, interest, or enthusiasm ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nonchalant)).

Neither of these are quite right for the specific sentence you provided, but could apply in many contexts where you want to describe someone who has a carefree or relaxed demeanor.